# How to solve summation (t+i)!/i! where i is from 1 to n.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factorial

I am solving a coding question and term is:

```
(t+1)!+(t+2)!/2!+......(t+n)!/n!
1<=t<=1000
1<=n<=10^11
```

and answer should be in modulo `1000000007 (10^9+7)`.

So I wrote code in cpp to find `(t+1)!`. So I am having `(t+1)!`. Now what are the approaches to solve it?

- I don't want to find factorial of each term because is expensive. I want to use the `(t+1)!` term for rest of the terms.
- I want to find modulo of each individual term and then find modulo of whole term using modulo property.

Comment: Then for next term, multiply by $(t+2)$ and divide by $2$. Next term: multiply by $t+3 $ and divide by $3$. Keep saving modulo if you wish for each term

Comment: @samjoe what if t is not divisible by 2? Then (t+1)! multiplied with this term will be in double but I want answer in integer.

Comment: It will be, it has to be

Comment: @samjoe but if I multiply (t+1)! and (t+2) and then divide by 2, then it will be definitely integer.

Comment: If you divide by $t!$ you get $\binom{t+1}{1}+\binom{t+2}{2}+...+\binom{t+n}{n}$. If you add $1=\binom{t+1}{0}$ and apply $\binom{m}{k-1}+\binom{m}{k}=\binom{m+1}{k}$. The whole thing collapses to $\binom{t+n+1}{n}$. Therefore, what you are computing is $t!\left(\binom{t+n+1}{n}-1\right)=\frac{(t+n+1)!}{n!}-t!=(n+1)(n+2)...(t+n+1)-t!$.

Comment: @arugula you forgot (t+1). It will be `(n+1)(n+2)...(n+t+1)/(t+1) - t!`